# Why are two ActionResult methods being invoked for my page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, friendly-url

I have an asp.net-mvc app with the following aspx pages served by my 'Users' controller: Index.aspx, User.aspx, UsersIntoActivity.aspx and UsersUsingLocation.aspx.

In my Global.ashx.cs I've got the following routes set up:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "UsersHome",
            "Users",
            new { controller = "Users", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
            "Users",
            "Users/{id}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Users", action = "User", id = "", name = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
            "UsersUsing",
            "Users/Using/{locationId}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Users", action = "UsersUsingLocation", locationId = "", name = "" });

routes.MapRoute(
            "UsersInto",
            "Users/Into/{activityId}/{name}",
            new { controller = "Users", action = "UsersIntoActivity", activityId = "", name = "" });
```

The problem is that when I try to access UsersIntoActivity.aspx or UsersUsingLocation.aspx via the urls 'website/Users/Into/1/some-activity' or website/Users/Using/1/some-location the appropriate ActionResult method is being invoked, but the User method also gets invoked afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine a second request to that route is coming from the browser for some reason. Try capturing the traffic between the browser and the web server using [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddlertool.com/Fiddler2/version.asp). This can help you rule-out the possibility that a 301/302 redirect is occurring or references to other resources exist in the rendered HTML (such as in an image, script, or link tag).

Comment: Ah funny you should mention images or other resources, as when the User(id, name) method is invoked, the arguments are something like "Images" and "MySiteLogo.png" which is rather strange.

Comment: David Liddle's response should sort that out.

Comment: See also this article: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/

Comment: One more thing, is there a way to get Fiddler to capture traffic when debugging my site from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

Following on from gWiz's reply, as a general rule after applying the mapping extension in IIS (for IIS 5 and 6), I then right click the properties of image and/or script FOLDERS and then remove the aspnet_isapi extension you just added. MVC routes will now not be called for file requests in these folders.

Alternatively setup an ignore route extension in your global asax.

```
this.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{*pathInfo}");
//e.g if your images, css, scripts are in a content folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using route debugger to check your routes:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

That should give you answer, what is really called.